# Producers in Errai

Tags: java, gwt, errai

Say I have a `@ApplicationScoped MyProducer` class which in turn have `@Produces MyModel model`, the question is, when I have anywhere in the app a `@Inject MyModel something` then this model would be whatever the value of `MyModel model` in the producer class/object, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe so.

Here is simple example how to use [CDI producers in Errai](https://docs.jboss.org/errai/1.3.2.Final/errai-cdi/reference/html/sid-5931498.html#sid-5931498_ErraiCDIFeatures-CDIProducers) and here is [full CDI spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/implementation.html#producermethod) about producers.